# Eclipse Kepler CDT “Symbol NULL could not be resolved”

Tags: java, c, eclipse, macos

To write C code, I use Eclipse keppler CDT (Service Release 1, Build id: 20130919-0819) on my Mac OS X 10.8.5 system.

Recently, I imported a complete C framework and added all the necessary include directories to the 'Includes' tab (context menu project - properties - C/C++ General - Paths and Symbols - 'Includes' tab).

NULL is defined in the 'stddef.h' file and can be found in one of my include directories, namely '/opt/local/lib/apple-gcc42/gcc/i686-apple-darwin12/4.2.1/include/stddef.h'.

The programs in the framework build and run successful. I rebuilt the index after adding the include directories, but eclipse still underlines all the NULL references and shows the “Symbol NULL could not be resolved” error. This is annoying when searching for other errors.

Can somebody help me?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Add this header file in c code 
"    stddef.h "